# How to get installed application path for executable in COM

Tags: visual-c++, com

I am trying to get the installed location of all application using COM. I am able to get the display name of each application. But I am not able to get installed path of each application.

MY Code:

```
CComPtr<IShellItem> spPrinters;
CoInitialize(nullptr);
HRESULT hresult = ::SHCreateItemFromParsingName(L"::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\\8\\"
    L"::{7B81BE6A-CE2B-4676-A29E-EB907A5126C5}", nullptr, IID_PPV_ARGS(&spPrinters));
CComPtr<IEnumShellItems> spEnum;
spPrinters->BindToHandler(nullptr, BHID_EnumItems, IID_PPV_ARGS(&spEnum));
for (CComPtr<IShellItem> spProgram; spEnum->Next(1, &spProgram, nullptr) == S_OK; spProgram.Release())
{
    CComHeapPtr<wchar_t> spszName;
    spProgram->GetDisplayName(SIGDN_NORMALDISPLAY, &spszName);
    CString cDisplayName = spszName;
}
```

Any idea how to get installed path from `IEnumShellItems`?

Comment: By installed path, do you mean the (optional) "Location" column?

Comment: yes; I want to get location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a piece of code that will dump this out. The child's IPropertyStore does not return these, I don't know why, so we have to use the *old*
 [IShellFolder2::GetDetailsEx method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775051.aspx) with a special column id (which is the same as a PROPERTYKEY).

```
CComPtr<IShellItem> cpl;
CComPtr<IShellFolder2> folder;
CComPtr<IEnumShellItems> enumerator;
PROPERTYKEY pkLocation;
SHCreateItemFromParsingName(L"::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\\8\\::{7B81BE6A-CE2B-4676-A29E-EB907A5126C5}", nullptr, IID_PPV_ARGS(&cpl));

// bind to IShellFolder
cpl->BindToHandler(NULL, BHID_SFObject, IID_PPV_ARGS(&folder));

// bind to IEnumShellItems
cpl->BindToHandler(NULL, BHID_EnumItems, IID_PPV_ARGS(&enumerator));

// get this property key's value
PSGetPropertyKeyFromName(L"System.Software.InstallLocation", &pkLocation);

for (CComPtr<IShellItem> child; enumerator->Next(1, &child, nullptr) == S_OK; child.Release())
{
    // get child's display name
    CComHeapPtr<wchar_t> name;
    child->GetDisplayName(SIGDN_NORMALDISPLAY, &name);
    wprintf(L"%s\n", name);

    // get child's PIDL
    CComHeapPtr<ITEMIDLIST> pidl;
    SHGetIDListFromObject(child, &pidl);

    // the PIDL is absolute, we need the relative one (the last itemId in the list)
    // get it's install location
    CComVariant v;
    if (SUCCEEDED(folder->GetDetailsEx(ILFindLastID(pidl), &pkLocation, &v)))
    {
        // it's a VT_BSTR
        wprintf(L" %s\n", v.bstrVal);
    }
}
```

Note it's using an undocumented `System.Software.InstallLocation` PROPERTYKEY. To find it I just dumped all columns with a code like this for each child:

```
    int iCol = 0;
    do
    {
        SHCOLUMNID colId;
        if (FAILED(folder->MapColumnToSCID(iCol, &colId)))
            break; // last column

        CComHeapPtr<wchar_t> name;
        PSGetNameFromPropertyKey(colId, &name);

        CComVariant v;
        if (SUCCEEDED(folder->GetDetailsEx(ILFindLastID(pidl), &colId, &v)))
        {
            if (v.vt == VT_BSTR)
            {
                wprintf(L" %s: %s\n", name, v.bstrVal);
            }
            else
            {
                wprintf(L" %s vt: %i\n", name, v.vt);
            }
        }

        iCol++;
    } while (true);
}
```

PS: I've not added much error checking, but you should.

Comment: Thank you @Simon. :) Just I added CoInitialize(NULL); otherwise SHCreateItemFromParsingName will return NULL. Any way I added error checking and it is working fine for me. Thanks again. :)

Comment: Yes, most shell functions need COM initialized.

Comment: @CrazyCoder, you should accept this answer before the bounty expires